# Getting Expect to interact until the program terminates

Tags: linux, cygwin, tcl, expect

I am using the Expect Linux tool and I have to interact with the shell. However, it's not a true interact, I just want to see what's going on. How can I get Expect to exit after the interacting program exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found it.

```
interact $
```

Will cause expect to exit when it encounters the string `$`.